# Update all SQL Server columns after SQL injection attack

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-injection

I have been notified that a company website we have has had a problem, and quickly I can see it had a SQL injection attack. I do not manage the website and have no access to the files (and know how I can prevent this in the future) but my current task is to clean the database. It seems there is HTML appended to almost all `varchar` columns in a Microsoft SQL Server database.

Is there any way in an easy query or function I can run to check all columns for the offending HTML and update the columns in all tables?

For example a column that was:

```
---------------------------
|Title
---------------------------
|product1
```

is now

```
---------------------------
|Title
---------------------------
|product1</title><style>.atpd{position:absolute;clip:rect(400px,auto,auto,400px);}</style><div class=atpd>Apply here <a href=http://abbypaydayloansonline.com >online payday loans</a></div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the leading tag always the same (`</title>`)? Is there a possibility that this string could appear naturally in any of the columns?

Comment: You may try search function of SSMS Tools http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/Features?f=5  It will search all columns in every table in the DB

Comment: @EricZ and will it clean them up too?

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand, it's search function only, after that, OP need run UPDATE script like you have below.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one option, assuming the offending text always starts with `</title>` and that `</title>` wouldn't naturally appear in the data.

```
UPDATE dbo.table_name
  SET Title = LEFT(Title, CHARINDEX('</title>', Title)-1)
  WHERE Title LIKE '%</title>%'
  AND Title LIKE '%abbypaydayloansonline.com%';
```

If you need to do this for multiple columns across multiple tables (assuming, again, that `</title>` appears first and `</title>` would never have appeared naturally in the data prior to the incident), you don't need an explicit cursor:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @sql = N'';

SELECT @sql = @sql + N'UPDATE ' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME([object_id]))
  + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME([object_id]))
  + ' SET ' + QUOTENAME(name) + ' = LEFT(' + QUOTENAME(name) 
  + ', CHARINDEX(''</title>'', ' + QUOTENAME(name) + ')-1)
  WHERE ' + QUOTENAME(name) + ' LIKE ''%</title>%''
  AND ' + QUOTENAME(name) + ' LIKE ''%abbypaydayloansonline.com%'''
  + ';' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
FROM sys.columns
WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY([object_id], 'IsMsShipped') = 0
AND system_type_id IN (35,99,167,175,231,239,231);

SELECT @sql;
-- EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Absolutely inspect the output before running it. Note that Management Studio will only show you a small subset of the actual command that will get executed, so you might also want to run this query to see all of the tables and columns that will be checked:

```
SELECT [table] = QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME([object_id]))
         + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME([object_id])),
      [column] = name
FROM sys.columns
WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY([object_id], 'IsMsShipped') = 0
AND system_type_id IN (35,99,167,175,231,239,231)
ORDER BY [table], [column];
```

Comment: This looks like it will work, but would I have to repeat this for all fields of all tables in the DB? This string is rampant and yes always starts with the same HTML snippet and there is no other similar text in any record.

Comment: @TomPennetta and are you sure that `</title>` would not naturally appear in the data in any of these columns? You were not storing HTML on purpose before this event happened?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't want to have to type in all your queries manually, I would recommend creating a `CURSOR` (as much as I hate cursors) and loop through the system tables, something like this:

```
SELECT t.name AS table_name,
SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS schema_name,
   c.name AS column_name
FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
```

Then you can run dynamic SQL to do something like @AaronBertrand suggested.

Declare your cursor and fetch your variables into @table_name and @column_name.   Then run something like (untested):

```
DECLARE @updateSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @updateSQL = 'UPDATE ' + @table_name + ' SET ' + @column_name + ' = LEFT(' + @column_name + ', CHARINDEX(''</title>'', ' + @column_name + ')-1)'
EXECUTE (@updateSQL)
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for this feedback, it looks like a viable option for sure.